# Ubuntu App Submission won't allow the "free" bubble to be checked

Tags: software-center, application-development

I am at the final stages of the Ubuntu App Developer Showdown, and I'm right at the point where I am submitting my app. The problem I run in to however, is that even though buy is at $0.00, it will not allow me to click on the "free" button, and keep that configuration saved. So when I go to "preview your app", it shows it saying "USD $0.00 ---- Buy" instead of saying "Free ---- Install". So I was wondering if it makes any difference or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Don't worry it is common

```
 Free of cost apps sumited through my apps portal will show $0.0 . If you really think it is a bug , submit a bugreport in launchpad
```

Comment: Ok thanks :D. I just didn't want it saying "Buy" when it was $0.00 anyways lol